# Nifi PutDatabaseRecord to update a table with where condition

Tags: apache-nifi

How to use PutDatabaseRecord to UPDATE only three columns of a table named student having several columns? I am trying to achieve following query with where clause using NiFi.

```
update student set class=v1,name=v2,section=v3 where 
id = v4
```

I am getting the values v1,v2,v3,v4 using ExecuteSQL processor. There can be 100 of students registered on the same date. So, v1,v2,v3,v4 will be array of json

```
 SELECT class,name,section,id
    FROM registration where registerd_on='20210530';
```

[image]

My PutDatabaseRecord config. I want to understand how to specify where condition here?

[image]

Comment: Update keys - A comma-separated list of column names that uniquely identifies a row. So you have to put `id` in it.

Comment: @daggett can we check in NiFi what Update query was generated by PutDatabaseRecord. I am not seeing any query in logs.

Comment: @daggett thanks, as suggested by you putting just id in Update Keys worked. If you can put that in answer I will accept that. Also, in general it will be helpful to know what Update query was generated by PutDatabaseRecord either in log or at Bulletin Level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to documentation

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/

`Update keys` - A comma-separated list of column names that uniquely identifies a row.

So you have to set  `Update keys = id` if you have just one column `id` as table row identifier.

About tracking sql queries. Try to add following line into `conf\logback.xml`

```
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord" level="DEBUG"/>
```

sometimes sql should appear in logs but truly i cant understand the logic in code...

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/PutDatabaseRecord.java